# Calling function from another javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html input button which calling this function

```
<button class="Go" onClick="go();" disabled><div class="inner first">Nah...Not Yet</div></button>
```

But this script I created in another javascript which code like this name "test.js"

```
function go()
{
    window.location.href = 'https://google.com';   
}
```

How should I input the scriptype for the input button in order to call this function?

Comment: No need for the semicolon in the onclick.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a  tag in your html, and all will be fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
```

Comment: Do you know any way to hide this ? for example. if i view page source. people able to see my test.js and download it. how i going prevent them?

Comment: If you want to hide the javascript inclusion, you have to do it serverside. It depends of your server language (if any). In Java, for instance, it could be `<%@include file="test.js" %>`